# Why sendError returns empty response body

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

I am trying to use sendError method from HttpServletResponse, but always get back an empty body response.

```java
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, 
                                @NonNull HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                @NonNull FilterChain filterChain)
                                    throws ServletException, IOException {

        String token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken(httpServletRequest);
        try {
            if (token != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
                Authentication auth = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            }
        } catch (CustomException ex) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            httpServletResponse.sendError(ex.getHttpStatus().value(), ex.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
}
```

Since it didn't work, I tried constructing my own response and return it to client (this is an API call).

```java
String error = "Expired or invalid JWT token";
ApiError errorResponse = new ApiError(new Date(),500, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, error, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), httpServletRequest.getRequestURL().toString());
httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(convertObjectToJson(errorResponse));
```

```java
private String convertObjectToJson(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
}
```

This works, but I had to construct it using string and then convert it to JSON. I want to just use the sendError method. Can someone help me figure out why the response body is always empty? The status code of the empty body response (when using sendError) is 403.

Answer (score 3):

I started having the same problem when I upgraded to spring boot 2.1 from 1.5.8.

Before the upgrade, the filter HeaderWriterFilter was not in the filter chain, it seems to be added by spring automatically. This filter is also calling your filter when sendError is called.

You did not mention if you are implementing Filter or extending a specific filter, but if you can extend OncePerRequestFilter it should fix the issue.

Comment: I also encountered this issue for a custom security filter after upgrading from Spring boot 1 series to the 2 series. I noticed in the logs that the filter seemed to be firing twice, and implementing OncePerRequestFilter did fix the issue, but I'm curious as to why the HeaderWriterFilter calls my filter a second time and why that causes the response body to be stripped. Can you expand upon your answer?

Answer (score 2):

For Spring Boot 2.3 and above, **Add below property**

in `application.yaml`

```
server:
  error:
    include-message: always
```

or in `application.properties`

```
server.error.include-message=always
```

**Note**:
This increases the risk of leaking information to a client.

**From Spring Boot 2.3 Release Notes**:

> The error message and any binding errors are no longer included in the
> default error page by default. This reduces the risk of leaking
> information to a client. server.error.include-message and
> server.error.include-binding-errors can be used to control the
> inclusion of the message and binding errors respectively. Supported
> values are always, on-param, and never.

**References**:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62069243/5384491
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63732087/5384491
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67582855/5384491

Comment: I did exactly that and it is still not working. I'm on spring boot 3.0.

Comment: Even in Spring boot 3.0, the same property is present in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.0/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix.application-properties.server:~:text=When%20to%20include%20%22message%22%20attribute.). 
To confirm, you can test the same in both spring boot 2.3 and 3.0, and notice for any differences.