# "message" field is empty in error response Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have handled unauthorized exception like this

```
@ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class UnauthorizedException extends RuntimeException {
    public UnauthorizedException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

but when I throw the error as follows

```
throw new UnauthorizedException("Invalid credentials");
```

I get the error message empty in the response as follows

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-05-27T13:44:58.032+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/auth/register"
}
```

I tried using,

```
throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid credentials");
```

but the result is still the same. When I added *spring-boot-devtools* dependency, I get the message as expected with the stack trace as well. How can I fix this?

Spring version : 2.3.0
Java Version: 11.0

Comment: Using spring-boot-devtools dependency; do you still get the message as expected _without_ throwing the new response exception?

Comment: I have the same problem. Call chain seems to go ResponseStatusExceptionResolver => ResponseFacade => Response#sendError, and at this point the message is still there.

Comment: Hi @Tony, yes I get the message as expected when spring-boot-devtools dependency is there.

Comment: I have spring-boot-devtools, and i don't have message in the response. I mean, it's just `null`, not empty string. The topicstarter's message is an empty string.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Ok got it, they have changed the default value for server.error.include-message to "never" (see the comment section here: [Spring 2.3.0 Release Info](https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/15/spring-boot-2-3-0-available-now)

All the default values are listed here:
[Spring Boot Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)

Just configure your application.yaml (or properties) like this.

```
server:
  error:
    include-message: always
    include-binding-errors: always
```

Mind that showing error messages may leak information about your server implementation.

Comment: Just for everyone else that needs clarification, to set it in properties use: `server.error.include-message= always`

Comment: when I run my app locally, it shows message with or without `server: error: include-message: always`. when I deploy it to ECS, message disappears. can anyone explain this? spring version is 2.6.2, devtools is included