# response.sendError(statusCode, "error message") not working after upgrading springboot to 2.4.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, spring-security

I am using `AuthenticationEntryPoint` to handle the Authentication issues.To deliver the exception reason to the end-user.

```
response.sendError(responseCode, "errorReason")
```

I recently upgraded the spring boot from "2.2.11.RELEASE" to "2.4.4". Since then it is not working anymore. It is not providing the "errorReason" in the response received by the client now. Is there any change recently introduced in spring-boot which I am missing?

Answer (score 10):

As of Spring Boot 2.3, [the message is no longer included in the error response by default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content):

> The error message and any binding errors are no longer included in the default error page by default. This reduces the risk of leaking information to a client. `server.error.include-message` and `server.error.include-binding-errors` can be used to control the inclusion of the message and binding errors respectively. Supported values are `always`, `on-param`, and `never`.

Setting `server.error.include-message=always` will restore Spring Boot 2.2's behavior.

Comment: Before upgrading the spring boot 2.3+ the timestamp of the errorResponse was in unix epoch time and after upgrading it's in ISO-8601. is there an easy way to have the timestamp as unix epoch time in spring boot 2.3+ ?

Comment: @wannix This Q&A is about the message. If you have a question about the timestamp, please ask it separately in a question of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot 2.4.4 uses Spring Security 5.4.5. `AuthenticationException` no longer has a getMessage method in this version ([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.6/api/org/springframework/security/core/AuthenticationException.html)). However it is still the same instance of `AuthenticationException` that you throw within your application. So you can use something like...

```java
if (authException instanceof CustomAuthenticationException) {
    CustomAuthenticationException ex = (CustomAuthenticationException) authException;
    // handle your exception
}
```

Comment: getMessage is coming from the ` java.lang.Throwable` class. and I am able to receive the message value here. but the problem is in the response received by the restclient  / Browser. Made my question a bit more clear now.

Comment: You should be able to throw an error with the HttpServletResponse object within the commence method as usual.. like `response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, ((CustomAuthException) authException).getCustomMessage());`